# Грабить и грабли

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Понятно, что слова "грабить" и "грабли" - однокоренные. Но от какого общего слова они произошли?
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И.-е. корень ghrebh передает ХАРАКТЕРНОЕ ДВИЖЕНИЕ руками, граблями, потом веслами, но уже на общеславянской почве у слова появляется переосмысленное значение - грести к себе, присваивать.

В Древней Руси грабить и расхищать "начинают" уже с 11 века, а грабеж и грабители появляются в 13 веке (словарь Срезневского). Самое позднее из производных - "грабиловка" из словаря Ушакова (1935 г.).